# Two signature adding not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

This is a simple Jquery or Javascript problem. When I add one signature it works fine, but a 2nd signature on the same page is not working. Can you please fix the error?

```js
var wrapper = document.getElementById("signature-pad1"),
  clearButton = wrapper.querySelector("[data-action=clear]"),
  saveButton = wrapper.querySelector("[data-action=save]"),
  canvas = wrapper.querySelector("canvas"),
  signaturePad;

function resizeCanvas() {
  var ratio = Math.max(window.devicePixelRatio || 1, 1);
  canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth * ratio;
  canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight * ratio;
  canvas.getContext("2d").scale(ratio, ratio);
}

window.onresize = resizeCanvas;
resizeCanvas();

signaturePad = new SignaturePad(canvas);

clearButton.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  signaturePad.clear();
});

saveButton.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  if (signaturePad.isEmpty()) {
    alert("Please provide signature first.");
  } else {
    window.open(signaturePad.toDataURL());
  }
});

// second signature
```

```css
.m-signature-pad {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #909090;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.27), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08) inset;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.m-signature-pad:before,
.m-signature-pad:after {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  content: "";
  width: 40%;
  height: 10px;
  left: 20px;
  bottom: 10px;
  background: transparent;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-3deg) rotate(-3deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-3deg) rotate(-3deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(-3deg) rotate(-3deg);
  -o-transform: skew(-3deg) rotate(-3deg);
  transform: skew(-3deg) rotate(-3deg);
  box-shadow: 0 8px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.m-signature-pad:after {
  left: auto;
  right: 20px;
  -webkit-transform: skew(3deg) rotate(3deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(3deg) rotate(3deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(3deg) rotate(3deg);
  -o-transform: skew(3deg) rotate(3deg);
  transform: skew(3deg) rotate(3deg);
}
.m-signature-pad--body {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  bottom: 60px;
  border: 1px solid #606060;
}
.m-signature-pad--body canvas {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02) inset;
}
.m-signature-pad--footer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  height: 40px;
}
.m-signature-pad--footer .description {
  color: #C3C3C3;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  margin-top: 1.8em;
}
.m-signature-pad--footer .button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
.m-signature-pad--footer .button.clear {
  left: 0;
}
.m-signature-pad--footer .button.save {
  right: 0;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .m-signature-pad {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    min-width: 250px;
    min-height: 140px;
    margin: 5%;
  }
  #github {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
  .m-signature-pad {
    margin: 10%;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-height: 320px) {
  .m-signature-pad--body {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 32px;
  }
  .m-signature-pad--footer {
    left: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    bottom: 4px;
    height: 28px;
  }
  .m-signature-pad--footer .description {
    font-size: 1em;
    margin-top: 1em;
  }
}
.red {
  color: #fa0312;
}
.normal-color {
  color: #202020;
}
.signs-box {
  padding: 1px 10px 10px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #D8D8D8;
}
.signs-box h3 {
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase!important;
}
.signs-box img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
#progress-bar {
  z-index: 8888888888888888!important;
  top: 0px!important;
}
.number-visard {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://secure.ascconnect.com/demov4/kiosk/sign/signature_pad.js"></script>
<div id="signature-pad1" class="m-signature-pad">
  <div class="m-signature-pad--body">
    <canvas></canvas>
  </div>
  <div class="m-signature-pad--footer">
    <div class="description">Sign above</div>
    <button type="button" class="button clear" data-action="clear">Clear</button>
    <button type="button" class="button save" data-action="save">Save</button>
  </div>
</div>

<hr>


<div id="signature-pad2" class="m-signature-pad">
  <div class="m-signature-pad--body">
    <canvas></canvas>
  </div>
  <div class="m-signature-pad--footer">
    <div class="description">Sign above</div>
    <button type="button" class="button clear" data-action="clear">Clear</button>
    <button type="button" class="button save" data-action="save">Save</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I repeat the code, the second signature box works but the first box doesn't.

Comment: you dont have any js code with signature-pad2. Can you share the code on fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it like below:-

1.Add jQuery library.

2.Change script code like below:-

```
var wrapper1 = document.getElementById("signature-pad1"),
    canvas1 = wrapper1.querySelector("canvas"),
    signaturePad1;

var wrapper2 = document.getElementById("signature-pad2"),
    canvas2 = wrapper2.querySelector("canvas"),
    signaturePad2;

function resizeCanvas(canvas) {
    var ratio =  Math.max(window.devicePixelRatio || 1, 1);
    canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth * ratio;
    canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight * ratio;
    canvas.getContext("2d").scale(ratio, ratio);
}

function clear1() { signaturePad1.clear(); }
function clear2() { signaturePad2.clear(); }

resizeCanvas(canvas1);
signaturePad1 = new SignaturePad(canvas1);

resizeCanvas(canvas2);
signaturePad2 = new SignaturePad(canvas2);

$("#signature-pad1 .clear").click(clear1);
$("#signature-pad2 .clear").click(clear2);
```

Working fiddle:- https://jsfiddle.net/7bfzunnn/

Comment: @LijoMattathil  glad to help you:):)